# Помогите определить род существительного "кули"

Tags: существительные, род

Малиновый кули или малиновое кули? (в значениии соус)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В **«Словаре кулинарных терминов»** использован **средний род.**

> **КУЛИ**
>
> …**Фруктовое** к. – это соус из сырых или готовых фруктов: ими могут
> быть красные фрукты (смородина, клюква, малина), желтые (абрикосы,
> слива мирабель), экзотические (киви).
>
> - - - (Источник: «Объединенный словарь кулинарных терминов»)
>
> [https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_culinary/1170/кули](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_culinary/1170/%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8)

В **«Кулинарной энциклопедии»** – **мужской**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что смело можете выбрать тот вариант, который Вам больше нравится.